# Android Grdiview not displaying correctly

Tags: android, gridview, resolution

We have built an online shopping app.

We have two layouts for gridview.
The first one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
tools:context=".HomeActivity">
<GridView
     android:id="@+id/gridView"
     android:numColumns="3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the second one for each gridview cell:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/singleCell"
android:layout_width="345px"
android:layout_height="400px"
android:background="#E6E6E6">

 <ImageView
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:id="@+id/profileImg"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="330px"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
    android:layout_marginTop="2px"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/friend_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="340px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
    android:textSize="13sp">
</TextView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is that in some devices the gridview is displayed correctly like this and the ratio is ok.

[gridview is displayed correctly on some devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWOQa.jpg)

but in several other devices, the images height and ratio changes and the image is displayed incorrectly.

[gridview is displayed incorrectly on some devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWKTx.jpg)

We would be happy if you give us a solution and help us. This is a critical problem as the gridcell image height changes and gets longer in some devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with changing the scale type of Imageview. Write this line

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

instead of

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Thanks @nazmul-hasan-masum. We tested your solution. Now the ratio is better but the problem is that a portion of the left and the right of the image doesn't display in those devices that had the problem before. Compare [the old one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uWKTx.jpg) with [the solution you provided](http://uploads.im/BH9SY.jpg). As you see, now the image ratio seems better but part of each cell on the right and left is cropped and it should be fit not cropped.

Answer (score 0):

@nazmul-hasan-masum, Thanks. I used your solution but at first the problem didn't get solved so I changed the imageview and text unit from px to the equivalent dp and everything is ok right now.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/singleCell"
    android:layout_width="345px"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:background="#E6E6E6">

     <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/profileImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1px"
        android:layout_marginRight="1px"
        android:layout_marginTop="2px"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20px"
        android:textSize="13sp">
    </TextView>

</FrameLayout>
```